# Update part of the table for a specific category

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's imagine I have a similar table to this one:

```
ID | Country | time      | location 1 | location 2 | count_clients
------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | PL      |2019-01-01 | JAK        | ADD3       | 23
2  | PL      |2019-03-01 | GGF        | ADD5       | 34
3  | PL      |2019-01-01 | J3K        | 55D3       | 67
4  | NL      |2019-04-01 | FDK        | AGH3       | 2
5  | NL      |2019-01-01 | GGK        | AFF3       | 234
```

It's an aggregated table. Source contains one row per client, in my table it's aggregated showing no. of clients per country, time, location 1 and location 2. It's updated by loading new rows only (new dates). First they are loaded to stage table then, after some modifications, to final table. The values loaded to stage table are already aggregated and stage table contains only new rows.

BUT I just learned that rows in source table can be deleted - it means the "count_clients" value can change or can be deleted. What's also important - I know which COUNTRY, location 1 and location 2 are affected but I don't know WHEN they were changed (was it before or after last load? I don't know).

Do you know any smart ways to handle it? I currently load new rows  + rows that were affected by change to stage tables, then remove affected rows from final table and load the stage rows to final table.

The source table is huge. I'm looking for a solution that will allow me to update only part of the table affected by the updates. Please remember that in stage table I have only new rows that needs to be inserted + the rows that was changed. I wanted to use the MERGE statement but to do that I would need to use a part of the table as a target not the whole table. I tried to do it but it didn't work.

I tried to do something like:

```
MERGE INTO (select country, time, location1, location 2, count from myFinalTable join stage table on country=country and location=location) --target = only rows affected by change
   USING myStageTable
      ON country = country and location=location
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE 
      SET count = count
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET then INSERT --insert new uploads
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE then DELETE
```

but it looks like I can't use the 'select' statement in target..?

Comment: Have you considered using triggers? Even if you don't use the trigger to actually update, you could use it to write to a "pending updates" table. That might help you do your next update - assuming you are doing the updates according to some schedule.

Comment: Hi Tom, Thanks! good idea, but if a row  (country, time, location 1, location2) was updated in the past it doesnt mean it can not be changed again

Comment: But that should be fine because each time you do get a row in your pending updates, you would update for the count,time,location, which would cover any update that might have been done.

Comment: ahh, yes! That's actually good point! I didn't get it at first. I will try to implement it.

Comment: @TomC Is it possible to create a trigger on server X on a table that is on server Y? (the "pending updates" table and the trigger would be on server X but the source table is on server Y). Unfortunately I am not able to create anything on server Y.

Comment: I tried to do it but I got an error: The object 'mysourcetable' does not exist or is invalid for this operation.

Comment: (I assume it's not possible, but it's always worth to ask)

Comment: No, that's the proverbial spanner. Is there perhaps a last update stamp of some sort? If so you will have to ensure an index and query against that. Not sure how you will find deleted rows through. Can you perhaps set up replication?

Comment: no actually there is no timestamp. There is only a "rollback flag" -> so I can identify the deleted rows but I am not able to tell when they were  deleted..